# Browser detection widget with browser suggestions

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, widget, browser-detection

I'm looking for a widget which displays the list of recommended browsers if the current browser does not match the criteria. I saw it several months ago, it displayed browser icons, and was very cool, but I cannot find it now ;-(

Google drops out only browser detectors with ugly text strips... :C

Comment: You probably don’t want to. See posts such as http://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/

Comment: The only type of widget I would suggest anybody even consider would be one that does something along the lines of http://browsehappy.com, suggesting people use a modern version of their preferred browser, rather than encouraging people to run off and download *your* favorite browser.

Comment: @dstorey: I have a SPA with XHR2 requirement because I want to use CORS. Funny sentence :D :D :D So I really need it, it is faster and cleaner than capability testing, and I can add a "continue anyways" button...

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: Yeye, this is I'm looking for... The widget I saw was similar... Maybe there is a browse happy widget out there, I can't remember the name :S

Comment: @inf3rno If there were a browsehappy widget, I suspect it would be mentioned on their page. This isn't really the approach you want to take, generally speaking. Instead, perform *feature-detection*, and deliver what you can. If a feature isn't support (like CORS), test for something like `XDomainRequest`, and drop back further to server-side proxy script if necessary. Otherwise, provide a different solution (if any at all). Some people can't upgrade their browsers, and it will frustrate them if you demand they do so.

Comment: I use lot of external libs, and I don't want to write test code for all of them... This is not the case where feature detection works, sorry... I did not found a browse happy toolbar, but it is similar than the widget I saw. (This is a private site, it is for about 50 ppl, and I will be in contact with them...)

Comment: @inf3rno Stack Overflow is for questions about *writing code*, and not so much about *finding widgets*. Sorry.

Comment: Nm, thanks for helping btw.

Comment: I'll write a widget like that :D It's about 10 mins there are a lot of browser detection code, so I need to display a similar bar like browse happy has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created my own toolbar: https://github.com/inf3rno/browsehappy-toolbar , it's not the best and its design sux, but it's working...